# My selenium webdriver script doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
package javapackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
public class SeleniumQuora {
public static void LaunchQuora()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\SBI SO\\Selenium\\Extracts\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.quora.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(13, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='__w2_lIh8Ilg_google_connect_button']/span")).click();

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LaunchQuora();}}
```

this code is supposed to click on "Continue with Google" option in the signIn page. But nothing happens. Its pretty basic I know but I searched most places and cant find the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? No browser window opening? What about logging output? stacktrace? How do you invoke the test on what OS?

Comment: No popup is displayed that should ask me to continue with my google ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are locating wrong element, In this [website](https://www.quora.com/) there is no element with the id `__w2_lIh8Ilg_google_connect_button` as I seeing, May be provided id is dynamically generated, So if you want to click on `Continue with Google` button simply try using `By.linkText()` as below :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\SBI SO\\Selenium\\Extracts\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://www.quora.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(13, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Continue with Google")).click();
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Perfect. It worked, Thank You Saurabh. Just out of curiosity, may I ask if I had to necessarily use xpath how would I have done it?

Comment: @ShashankShukla there is no need use `xpath` but if ask for xpath you can use xpath with their class instead of id because id is dynamically generated here, you can use this `xpath` : `//a[@class = 'google_button submit_button']`